# Error for remplace %20 for (-) in the url

Tags: php, .htaccess

currently I am doing what is called friendly URL, and I have an error what happens is that I manage to substitute %20 (spacing) of the urls correctly by (-) but when entering the link by a button of my web this (%20) appears again.

By typing the url in the browser on my own:

localhost/blog/21/este-es-un-ejemplo | works correctly

---

but when you enter through a button on my website this happens:
localhost/blog/21/este%20es%20un%20ejemplo

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^([^/]*?)(?:/|%20)+([^/]+?(?:/|%20)+.*)$"
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1-%2 [N,NE]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^([^/]*?)(?:/|%20)+([^/]+?)/?$"
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1-%2/ [L,R=302,NE]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) blog.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC]
```

index.php

```
<a href="blog/<?php echo $post['id']?>/<?php echo $post['title']?>">
```

Comment: ok why not do `preg_replace` for `$post['title']`

Comment: use `$post['guid']`. `<a href="<?php echo $post['guid']?>">`

Comment: @anubhava | What should that function be like?

Comment: @admcfajn | Undefined index: guid

Comment: `<a href="blog/<?php echo $post['id']?>/<?php echo preg_replace('/%20|\s/', '-', $post['title'])?>">`

Comment: @anubhava | Very thanks you!

Comment: index['guid'] would (hopefully) be the permalink column in the wp_posts table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't need any changes in .htaccess rules since you're already using PHP code to present a `href` link. You can use:

```
<a href="blog/<?php echo $post['id']?>/<?php echo preg_replace('/%20|\s/', '-', $post['title'])?>">
```

Comment: Wow you know PHP also that's great